# C++ cout then cin hanging

Tags: c++, cin, cout

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void doOneSet();

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    doOneSet();

    return 0;
}

void doOneSet() {
    int answer;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << (rand() % 100) << " + " << (rand() % 101) << ": ";
        cin >> answer;
    }
}
```

The following code hangs, and never outputs the `cout` statement, and also doesn't get the get the `cin` statement. When I end the `cin` statement as follows, it works fine, but I'm not sure why. I want to have the input on the same line, not on the next line.

```
cout << (rand() % 100) << " + " << (rand() % 101) << ": " << endl;
```

I've been able to do this easily before, but for some reason I'm having an issue now, not sure why. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `cout` line buffered?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Include information about your programming environment if necessary. The code as shown is correct (the missing include aside).

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you replace `int answer` with `std::string answer`? Input to a string is much more permissive.

Comment: I added <time.h>, also I tried changing int answer to std::string answer and it changed nothing. I'm also using XCode on Mac.

Comment: Doesn't hang on VS, oh you microsoft.

Comment: The code works fine for me with VS2017 (with ctime header included).

Comment: Works with GCC 6.2 as well.

Comment: Could not reproduce the problem

Comment: Well, I looked through previous algorithms I've made, and I've never had this issue. Using cout then cin automatically flushes, but now it's not. I'm assuming I changed some setting or something... Thanks for all the help guys! I appreciate it!

Comment: "XCode on Mac" this could be the problem. Start a regular terminal and run from there. XCode "terminal window" may or may not behave like a normal terminal.

Comment: You're right, I ran it in the terminal using g++, and it worked perfectly. I'm thinking I changed the compiler or some setting to where it's not working correctly in XCode now

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for future searchers, I just hit this issue.
I was setting up a new PC and installed VS2019 then remembered I needed VS2013 installed too to support legacy builds. A simple Hello World app would hang on the cout.

I reran the VS2019 install as Repair and, following the reboot, cout behaves as expected.

Answer (score -1):

I could not reproduce your behavior in g++ 4.9.4, but I have an idea. You could try using the **fflush** function which flushes the buffer of a stream. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void doOneSet();

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    doOneSet();

    return 0;
}

void doOneSet() {
    int answer;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << (rand() % 100) << " + " << (rand() % 101) << ": ";
        fflush(stdout);
        cin >> answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: We already had that answer. No, there is no need to flush manually, reading from `std::cin` automatically flushes `std::cout`. So this is wrong.

Comment: Also, `#include <stdlib.h>` etc is deprecated since 1998, time to have a look at some up to date book or documentation.

Comment: Didn't know **stdlib.h** is deprecated in C++ as I have a C background and it is not deprecated there. I edited it to `#include <cstdlib>`. Anyway, from what I've read this C++ header is pretty much the same thing just mapped into the std namespace.

Comment: This answer was just an idea, because I know that `std::cin` should normally flush stdout. He said he was using an XCode terminal, and maybe that terminal behaves differently.